# How do I list my items by when they will be out of inventory

Tags: sql

I have a table that lists items in my inventory, the total quantity on hand, order qty and ship date.

```
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | Items | QtyOnHand | QtyOrdered | ShipDate |
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
    | Itema | 100       | 80         | 3/4/14   |
    | Itemb | 80        | 220        | 3/8/14   |
    | Itema | 100       | 80         | 3/10/14  |
    | Itemb | 80        | 100        | 3/12/14  |
    +-------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

I would like a return like this that includes the item, date we are out of inventory and the amount over the inventory we are on that date.

Note: the same item is generally on the list multiple times and this is a representation of actual sales orders. The qty on hand number is the total on hand for that item TODAY and will be the same every time the item is listed.

My issue is that if item a ships 80 cases on 3/4/14 and has 100 on hand then with 20 left over the shipment of 80 cases on 3/10/14 will be 60 cases short so the query will return item a 3/10/14 -60. To indicate that based the current on hand values, on 3/10/14 item a will not have adequate inventory to cover the order.

```
Itemb 3/8/14 -140
Itema 3/10/14 -60
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ken

Comment: How do you know the `QtyOnHand` in the future?  This seems like a suspicious data structure.

Comment: I don't know the future qtyonhand. For every scheduled ship date all I know is what I have on hand today. We are acting as if we don't receive any new inventory when in the shipping schedule will we run out of inventory.

Comment: I think you may need to be more specific about the date out of inventory. You would have to have some additional information such as the average sold per month to get an idea when you would be out of inventory.  Even then it would only be an estimate.   Or did you mean you wanted the ship date for the next available item?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want something like this:

SELECT Items,ShipDate,(QtyOnHand-QtyOrdered) 
from *TableName* 
where (QtyOnHand-QtyOrdered) < 0

Comment: This would only be true if the current order line exceeded the total on hand total. However when the list has multiple orders for a specific item and each rode is less than the current qty on hand, each order for am item in date order would come out of the current on hand total and what I'm looking for is the date the inventory runs out.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which DBMS you're using. MSSQL 2012 makes this fairly simple:

```
WITH cteInventory (Items, ShipDate, Stock) As
(
  SELECT
    Items,
    ShipDate,
    QtyOnHand - Sum(QtyOrdered) OVER (PARTITION BY Items ORDER BY ShipDate)
  FROM
    Inventory
)
SELECT
  Items,
  Min(ShipDate) As Date,
  Max(Stock) As Stock
FROM
  cteInventory
WHERE
  Stock < 0
GROUP BY
  Items
ORDER BY
  Date
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0573/3)

Comment: Sorry, I am using SQL 2005